# is there any way to use nested method reference like HashSet::new::add in java any version that can be use in parameter for common method?

Tags: java

Suppose in this example, I have two object User and Address that is given below:

```
public User{
  private String name;
  private Address address;
 // setter, Getter
}

public Address{
  private String country;
 // setter, Getter
}
```

I want to find the country from the user so I can simply use

```
user.getAddress().getCountry();
```

to get address with the help of method reference, It can be passed in parameter like

```
User::getAddress
```

but I have to find out the country name and I want to use in method reference way so how can I do?

Comment: What do you mean by “real-time example”?

Comment: Real-time example means, What I was trying to do at that time.

Comment: ["Real-time"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_computing) has a specific meaning in computing, FYI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't want to use map() multiple times so I asked this question.
generally, I want to write a generic method where I get User or Address any properties by passing it from parameter, So I have used like given below:

```
private String getCountryName(User user, Function<? super User, String> mapper) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(user)
                .map(mapper)
                .get();
    }
```

Thanks for your great suggestion, andThen() is the way that I was wondering.
with the help this I can use like :

```
String username = getCountryName(vikash, User::getName);

Function<User, Address> getAddress = User::getAddress;
String countryName = getCountryName(vikash, getAddress.andThen(Address::getCountry));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a utility function to compose two method references:

```java
public class Foo {
    static class AClass {
        private final BClass b = new BClass();

        public BClass getB() {
            return b;
        }
    }

    static class BClass {
        public String getFoo() {
            return "foo";
        }
    }

    static <A,B,C> Function<A,C> compose(Function<A,B> ab, Function<B,C> bc) {
        return ab.andThen(bc);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        System.out.println(Optional.of(new AClass()).map(AClass::getB).map(BClass::getFoo));
        System.out.println(Optional.of(new AClass()).map(compose(AClass::getB, BClass::getFoo)));
    }
}
```

Comment: With [`Function.andThen(Function)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html#andThen-java.util.function.Function-), the implementation of `compose` can be simplified to `return ab.andThen(bc)`.

Comment: Thanks @tgdavies, I think .andthen() is the way that can solve this issue

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly refer to getCountry () via User, but you can use stream to map to addresses and then reference getCountry ().
However, you should specify in what situation you want to use.

but e.g if you have a user list, you can do this:

```
List <User> users = List.of(
                       user,
                       user1);

 users.stream()
                .map(User::getAddress)
                .map(Address::getCountry)
                .forEach(System.out::println)
```

Comment: You need to give a reason when answering a question. New answers without any explanation how they complement other answers tend to get deleted in the review process.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to compose multiple chained functions is to assign the first method reference to a local variable and apply `.andThen(Other::ref)`:

```
Function<User, Address> user2Address = User::getAddress;
Function<User, String> user2Country  = user2Address.andThen(Address::getCountry);
```

You can chain as many `.andThen(Other::ref)` as you need to reach the target mapping and use the combined function as one step in say 'stream.map` operations.

```
List.of(user1, user2,user3).stream()
    .map(user2Country)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Thanks @DuncG, for helping me to solve this issue.